# Task Scheduler differentiate between AC and battery power in Win 7?

Tags: battery, windows-task-scheduler

Is there a way to differentiate between AC and battery power on a laptop to be used in Win 7 Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set bstat=
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic path Win32_Battery get BatteryStatus /value ^| find "="') do set bstat=%%a
if [%bstat%]==[1] echo The battery is discharging.
if [%bstat%]==[2] echo The system has access to AC so no battery is being discharged. However, the battery is not necessarily charging.
if [%bstat%]==[3] echo Battery fully charged.
if [%bstat%]==[4] echo Battery low.
if [%bstat%]==[5] echo Battery critical.
if [%bstat%]==[6] echo Battery charging.
if [%bstat%]==[7] echo Battery charging and high.
if [%bstat%]==[8] echo Battery charging and low.
if [%bstat%]==[9] echo Battery charging and critical.
if [%bstat%]==[10] echo Battery status undefined.
if [%bstat%]==[11] echo Battery partially charged.
```

The batch file above uses the [Win32_Battery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class to get the battery status. Extend it to perform the required action(s), then use task scheduler to run it as and when required.

Comment: Excellent, it is quite strange. I thought it would have been a recorded event. Would +1, cannot at present. Will do when I get +15. Thanks

Comment: This is the only standalone solution. Awesome. Thanks